# Nginx location alias + redirection

Tags: redirect, nginx

I want to be able, if the request tries to access `<host>/.well-known/acme-challenge/` to serve the matching file if found.

If the request is something else, I want to redirect it to `https://`

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name my_example.com;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        alias /var/www/encrypt/.well-known/acme-challenge/;
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Problem is when accessing to `my_example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/12345` which exist in alias path, i'm **still** redirected to https:// and the browser doesn't download the file.

How can I just serve the file and not apply the redirection in this case ?

Thanks

Comment: EXACTLY the same setup as us

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place the `return` statement inside a `location` block:

For example:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name my_example.com;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/encrypt;
    }
    location / {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Also, simplified your other `location` block.

Comment: your location suggestion `/` will match all other request right ?

Comment: @sf_tristanb Yes, you can think of it as the default location block.

Comment: Thank you @Richard Smith