# ssl fails with 404

Tags: ssl, nginx, dns

I have a nginx file configured to redirect my www address to non-www. It works correctly but when I try to get an ssl certificate for the www address it fails with a 404 error.

I wouldn't bother with it but I'm trying to improve SEO and the www address returns `ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID` for the https site which seems to reduce SEO.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Here's my nginx config for the redirects. I also have an A name DNS record with the www address setup, would that affect it?

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.example.com.au;
  return 301 https://example.com.au$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/domain.access.log;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/domain.error.log debug;
  server_name www.example.com.au;
  ssl certificates...
  return 301 https://example.com.au$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Neither of those blocks generate a 404 response. What do you mean by trying to get an SSL certificate? For example, Let's Encrypt might use `http://www.example.com/.well-known/...` to access a token, whereas your configuration will simply redirect it to your other site.

Comment: You're right the address doesn't return a 404 response but the acme challenge url does: `raise ValueError("Wrote file to {0}, but couldn't download {1}: {2}".format(wellknown_path, wellknown_url, e))
ValueError: Wrote file to /var/www/letsencrypt/.well-known/acme-challenge/F7qFpSzL2GWPiJuUZhez_SLxN9xcBIkYwYQHuo4BvHI, but couldn't download http://www.mydomain.com.au/.well-known/acme-challenge/...: Error:
Url: http://www.mydomain.com.au/.well-known/acme-challenge/F7qFpSzL2GWPiJuUZhez_SLxN9xcBIkYwYQHuo4BvHI`
Data: None
Response Code: 404

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files, and ensure that the above `server` blocks are present with the correct `server_name`. But the main problem is there is now way to serve URIs like `/.well-known/acme-challenge/`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43232445/nginx-location-alias-redirection/43234091#43234091).

Comment: You're a legend thanks mate. In my case it was `root /var/www/letsencrypt`. I'll add the full snippet below.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the following snippet solved it for me (adding the root and location blocks):

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.example.com.au;
  root /var/www/letsencrypt;

  location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    default_type "text/plain";

    try_files $uri =404;
  }

  location / {
    return 301 https://example.com.au$request_uri;
  }
}
```